# Our proof for $\left(1+rx\right)$ is invertible if $r\in J\left(R\right)$ and $x\in R$ doesn't seem to make any sense

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

It goes as follows:

$$r\in J\left(R\right)\Leftrightarrow r\in \bigcap _{m\in Max\:R}\:m\:$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \:\forall _{m\in Max\:R}\:r\in m$$

$$\Rightarrow \:\forall _{m\in Max\:R}\:\forall _{x\in R}\:\:rx\in m$$

$$\Rightarrow \:\forall _{m\in Max\:R}\:\forall _{x\in R}\:\:\left(1+rx\right)\notin m$$

$$\Rightarrow \:\forall _{m\in Max\:R}\:\forall _{x\in R}\:\forall _{s\in m}\:\:s\cdot \left(1+rx\right)\in m$$

And this should prove that (1+rx) is invertible. Note that $\forall _{m\:}1\notin m$ by definition, so the last line we get cannot tell us that it's invertible, as there is no 1 in any m.

Comment: The last line is absolutely obvious and follows simply from the definition of an ideal. Anyway, the proof is pretty much finished in the line before that, because it is known that every non invertible element belongs to some maximal ideal.

Comment: But just because every noninvertible element belongs to some maximal ideal, this does not mean that every there are no noninvertible elements outside of those maximal ideals

Comment: Yes, but the fourth line tells us that given $x\in R$, the element $1+rx$ doesn't belong to any maximal ideal. So I say it immediately follows that $1+rx$ is invertible.

Comment: But why should every element which does not belong to any maximal ideal be invertible?

Comment: Because as I explained in the first comment, every noninvertible element belongs to some maximal ideal. So if an element does not belong to any maximal ideal then it has to be invertible.

Comment: If $x$ is noninvertible then the ideal generated by $x$ is proper and therefore, by Zorn's Lemma, $x$ belongs to some maximal ideal of $R$